# Take one table values and insert it into another Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to insert the table 2 values into table 1.

My tables

**Table 1**

```
       Month   Gender    State  Load     DepartmentID DeptName  Count1 Count2 Count3
         Jan   Male       va    FullTime   100         HR         2      0      1
         Jan   Male       VA    PartTime   100         HR         1      3     13
         Jan   Female     Va    FullTime   100         HR         2      1     21
         Jan   Female     VA    PartTime   100         HR         0      0     0
```

**Table 2**

```
       Month   Gender    State  Load     DepartmentID DeptName  Count1 Count2 Count3
         Jan   Male       va    FullTime   220         Mhrm         2      0      1
         Jan   Male       VA    PartTime   220        Mhrm         1      3     13
         Jan   Female     Va    FullTime   220        Mhrm         2      1     21
         Jan   Female     VA    PartTime   220         Mhrm         0      0     0
```

The table1 has a lot more values.... But I am trying to add the Department ID 220 and Dept Name Mhrm to Table 1. How can I achieve this?

**EDIT:**

The above tables are not direct tables, but couple of views and a lot of conditions combined. I wanted to know how I can combine then dynamically without changing any data on the tables.

Comment: **DepartamentID** is a **identity** field? because if it isn't then you shoud do the following query: **INSERT INTO TABLE2(FIELD1,...,FIELDN) SELECT FIELD1,...,FIELDN FROM TABLE1**.

Comment: You could also logo at the merge function http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

Comment: I have tried doing union and union all , it works but that is not exactly what I am looking at.

Comment: I Cannot insert values into the actual table and I cannot create another table ..So performance wise it is taking a bit over 10sec to execute this query.. Cause for me to arrive at the above Tables I had to write a long query it self............

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that **DepartamentID** is not a identity field, try this query:

```
    INSERT INTO TABLE2(FIELD1,...,FIELDN)
    SELECT FIELD1,...,FIELDN FROM TABLE1.
```

Otherwise, you should run this before:

```
    set identity_insert TABLE2 ON
    --INSERT QUERY
    set identity_insert TABLE2 OFF
```

Comment: Just curious... why do you think DepartmentId would be an identity field.  If it was an identity column, I would expect to see different values for each row.

Comment: @GMastros: Ups, you're right, sorry. I think assumed that when I read the first line of the question. In this case, DepartamentID not be an identity field.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO table1
SELECT * FROM table2;
```

Comment: It's a million times better to specify the column names.  This query not only assumes the column names are the same, but also that the order of the columns is the same.  This is a long term recipe for disaster.

Comment: Be careful, because if **DepartmentID** is a identity field, this query will not work. In that case you should enable **indentity_insert** mode.

Comment: Thanks for the warnings. Without more information regarding the OP's context I preferred to choose the easiest solution, assuming that the OP will provide more information if the answer doesn't satisfy his needs.