# Enable an identity column that already has data in it?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Someone disabled the identity column of a table in a SQL DB. Is it possible to re-enable that feature of the column even when there is already data in the table? And maintain the existing identity values?

I know I could copy the data to another table and reinsert it after setting Identity_Insert on.

Comment: You can re-enable it in the visual designer in SQL Server Mgmt Studio, but this really only re-creates the table with the `IDENTITY`, renames the old name, copies over the data, and then drops the old name. That's what you have to do in T-SQL script, too - there's no way to just switch on the `IDENTITY` on an existing column

Comment: Please see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17200813/1563878), i posted an insert statement with enable and disable identity. Also there to reset or change the next identity value ([link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/15/sql-server-dbcc-reseed-table-identity-value-reset-table-identity/)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot *switch on* the `IDENTITY` on an existing column, that's just not possible in SQL Server right now (at least up to version 2012).

What you need to do is exactly what you describe:

- create the new table in the structure you want, *with* the `IDENTITY` column
- copy the data from the existing table into the new table, with `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON`
- drop the old table
- rename the new table to the old table name

You can "re-enable" the identity specification in the visual table designer in SQL Server Mgmt Studio, but this really only does those above steps in the background, for you.

Answer (score 3):

Just as *marc_s* said you can use

I dont know if there is any other way to do this but you can use

```
    CREATE TABLE tblNewTable
    (
         //Put the columns and datatypes of the former table
    )

    INSERT INTO tblNewTable
    AS
    SELECT * FROM oldTable
```

Then drop the table usng

```
    DROP TABLE oldTable
```

Then recreate the new table and add the identity column, then use

```
   INSERT INTO tblNewRecreatedTable (//Columns of the new created table except the column with the identity
   AS
   SELECT //Columns of the table you copied the data to except the Columned that you  defined identity
```

I hope it helps